# magento console errors when script is written in header

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, console

In header we have code like this in separate scripts

```
var $ck = jQuery.noConflict();
var $abc = jQuery.noConflict();
var $frr = jQuery.noConflict();
```

The requirement is working but I have observed in the console

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ReferenceError: decorateList is not defined
ReferenceError: Varien is not defined
```

Please find the below image

[image]

can anyone help me on this issue.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried loading your script after all the other scripts have loaded?

Comment: yes my code is after all below

Comment: Can you post an image of the loaded scripts and mark the custom scripts you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your custom scripts before the jQuery and Varien Library loads. So only you are facing that issue. Initiate your custom scripts in the body after the header loads. Then I think it will works as expected.

Comment: we have header related divs in the script. so if we move the script to body i think script will not work